# How to perform session in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have created an application with login and logout. But after clicking back it goes to the user name and pass form page.. it doesn't destroy the session.. how is it possible to destroy session in django??

Comment: If by "clicking back" you mean the back button of the browser, then it should not destroy session. Your question is vague. Please explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete the key from the session in the relevant method in `views.py`.

```
del request.session['your key']
```

You can see more on the [sessions here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved)

Comment: This should simply be done in any method that you make a request with. Can you please update your question with more clarity and code so i can better help

Answer (score 0):

Going 'back' to the login page should not automatically logout the user or clear the session. You should provide an explicit 'Logout' link on your UI. This should call standard Django logout functionality.